# How to make booking form in my wordpress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

How to integrate a booking form to wp theme based on wpbakery pagebuilder? I have heard about some extensions like custom form builder, but will they solve my problem?

Comment: When you say booking form do you mean a contact form with some date related input fields that sends you an email or are you looking for a comprehensive system in WP to manage bookings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try the Contact Form 7 plugin for wordpress?

Comment: Yes, sure, but it is only about contact form, nothing more I suppose